# how to visualize csv data every 10 rows in QGIS

Tags: qgis, data, csv, filter

I have imported a csv file in QGIS. The file contains 1 column with 43000 rows of data. I want to apply a filter to visualise data only every 10 rows in order to make more clear the graphics.

Please can you suggest me which type of filter I can use ?

Answer (score 12):

Assuming you don't have a unique id field, you can use rule based symbols with the following filter

```
$id % 10  = 1
```

The % sign is equivalent to remainder, so any row that divides by 10 with a remainder, i.e, every 10th row will remain while the others will be filtered out of the result.

[image] 
[image]
[image]